# Add action to option on Select (Angular 4)

Tags: angular, typescript

I want Angular to execute the function "onEditClick" when the user click on an specif option, here's my code:

```
<select class="form-control">
  <option *ngFor="let skill of skills" (click)="onEditClick(skill)" >{{ skill.name }}</option>
</select>
```

When I click on any option, nothing happens.

I tried doing it with a table instead of select and it worked:

```
<tbody *ngFor="let skill of skills">
  <td> {{ skill.name }} </td>
<td><button class="btn btn-outline-success" height="20" width="20" (click)="onEditClick(skill)">Edit</button></td>
</tbody>
```

How do I do it with the Select one?

Comment: What do you mean by nothing happened?

Comment: DOM 'option' elements won't call the event, you can listen for 'change' event at the selector.

Comment: @JakubChlebowicz I changed the (click) to (change) and moved it to on the select tag. It's still not working

Answer (score 22):

Click event is not valid option for select, you should use change event

```
 <select class="form-control" (change)="onEditClick($event.target.value)">
   <option *ngFor="let skill of skills">
      {{ skill.name }}
   </option>
 </select>
```

then in your component do something with that

`onEditClick(skill: any) {
        console.log('skill name', skill)
    }`

You can also pass some other parameter of skill object as a value like id, using `[value]="skill.id"`

`<option *ngFor="let skill of skills" [value]="skill.id">`

But if you want to get full *skill* object maybe you can do this with [(ngModel)] and (change), like this:

```
<select class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedSkill" 
(change)="getSelectedSkill()">
 <option *ngFor="let skill of skills" [ngValue]="skill">
    {{ skill.name }}
 </option>
</select>
```

and than in your component :

`selectedSkill: any`

`getSelectedSkill(){
    console.log(this.selectedSkill)
 }`

Comment: Hi, I need same option to be clicked again, So What should I do? (change) method only works if the option get changed right?